# bundling multiple js files

Tags: javascript, webpack

in react using webpack every js files is bundle into a single bundle.js , for my normal html , css, js application for example , i am having 6 libraries. for an example consider

i am using jquery and bootstrap min versions. so if i reference two files the request will be two. so how can i make it into a single file. So there will be a single request.

like when i checked the file size is about in kb's and the request is processed within less that 1 or 2 seconds , like the chrome dev tools shows the time for to load also it parrallely loads the two files.

But how can i bundle the two librarys using webpack and get a single  file that i can refer in my application.

i am a beginner to webpack

Answer (score 0):

You need to import them in your entry point file and Webpack will handle the bundling. As you have worked with React, I assume you have basic command line skills.

You can read the [Getting Started guide](https://webpack.js.org/guides/getting-started/) which bundles Lodash like how you are trying to bundle jQuery and Bootstrap.

First of install, ensure that you are installing jQuery, Bootstrap, and any other libraries using [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/) (or [yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/), if you prefer):

```
# Install Webpack as a dev dependency
npm install webpack webpack-cli --save-dev

# Install dependencies (I've added Popper.js as Bootstrap requires it)
npm install jquery bootstrap popper.js
```

Create a folder called `src` and a file inside there called `index.js`. This is your [entry point](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/#entry) and Webpack will look for this file unless configured differently. Import the libraries like this:

```
import $ from 'jquery'
import 'bootstrap'

// Do something with jQuery
$(document).ready(() => console.log('Hello world!'))
```

Then run Webpack using [npx](https://medium.com/@maybekatz/introducing-npx-an-npm-package-runner-55f7d4bd282b):

```
npx webpack
```

A file named `main.js` should be created in a folder called `dist` that contains the bundled code. This is your [output](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/#output) file. You can use a `<script>` tag in your HTML file to load this JavaScript:

```
<!-- assuming your index.html is in the dist folder -->
<script src='main.js'></script>
```

Once you get here, you can explore more advanced things like importing Bootstrap components individually, minifying code, multiple bundles, transpiling TypeScript, etc.

You will likely need to add a [Webpack configuration file](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/) very soon as there is only so much that can be done using zero-config mode.

Answer (score 0):

Good practice is to keep two sepearate bundles for the application logic and external libraries and in webpack this can be achieved by the following code,

`app.js` - appliation index file,

`vendors.js` - import all external libraries in this file

`entry: { 
  app: './src/app.js',
  vendors: './src/vendors.js'
}`

To get a single file, import vendors.js file inside app.js file and give entry key in webpack as

`entry: './src/app.js'`

Comment: This will produce two files, and I think DILEEP THOMAS just want one unique file.

Comment: modified the answer @PierreCapo. Importing vendors.js file in app.js will generate single file.

Answer (score -1):

Let us assume that you have the files in src directory. You can merge multiple files by specifying them in webpack.config.js to have a single named file as an output. I hope this is what you are looking for.

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
  'bundle.js': [
   path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/file1.js'),
   path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/file2.js')
  ]
},
output: {
filename: 'bundle.js',
path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
},
module: {
    rules: [{
        exclude: /node_modules/ 
    }]
}
};
```

As above, the two files "file1.js" and "file2.js" will be combined into a single file "bundle.js" and stored in "dist" directory.
You can also exclude node_modules by specifying a rule in module object of webpack configuration.